# WebStorm adds needless destination path

Tags: ide, webstorm

WebStorm adds some extra path for existing. Guess that it's project configuration problem.

[image]

```
media/fonts/.../... .tff
```

[image]

`media/font/.../ ... .tff` -- **same as above**

[image]

`media/css/media/font` -- unnecessary first two folders.

WebStorm destination

[image]

I can temporary fix it just by adding fonts into `media/css`, but it's not right.

Comment: Need some clarification here .. as I do not see where **WebStorm** adds such extra path. Request is done by the browser .. so it's the way how it interprets what you have written. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @LazyOne I suppose, that from which file I'm currently sitting, in this example in **media/css/style.css**, webstorm adding this prefix for inserted files

Comment: What do you mean by "inserted files" exactly? Accordingly to your css file the URL requested is correct -- `src: url(` there does not start with leading `/` so it's interpreted relative to the current file. As I understand the complaint is "why WebStorm have added `media/` part when I was completing the path to the font file -- in `src:` attribute". If so --  what did you do to get that path -- used autocomplete? if so -- how (what did you typed etc)? Something else (e.g. drag and drop)? The correct path to that file considering your CSS file location should be `../fonts/....`